# Spark with neo4j connector, neo4j times out?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j

EDIT: I have tried several things to get this to work to completion and nothing seems to work:

Updated the neo4j-community.vmoptions:

```
-server
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:NewSize=1024m
```

Also updated my mac to handle more threads.

```
C02RH2U9G8WM:~ meuser$ ulimit -u
709
C02RH2U9G8WM:~ meuser$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Finally ran a test to make sure it wasnt limited harddrive space that was causing the issues.   Everything seemed to check out, and during execution I would check my thread usage in another window....

```
jstack -l 'pid' | grep tid | wc -l

and

ps -elfT | wc -l
```

Nothing seemed out of hand so I am really confused as to why I am getting the errors below when running spark code in scala connecting to neo4j that runs fine with small set of answers but blows up when I let it rip on everything.

note: in my code I do not use `sc.stop()` or anything even though I think resources need to be cleared somehow while running a decently sized loop from within spark/scale

I did check the logs, turns out it might be memory related?

```
2017-10-13 01:17:45.073+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.t.SocketTransportHandler] Fatal error occurred when handling a client connection: unable to create new native thread unable to create new native thread
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Neo4jJobScheduler.schedule(Neo4jJobScheduler.java:94)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.concurrent.ThreadedWorkerFactory.newWorker(ThreadedWorkerFactory.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.MonitoredWorkerFactory.newWorker(MonitoredWorkerFactory.java:54)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltKernelExtension.lambda$newVersions$1(BoltKernelExtension.java:234)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.transport.ProtocolChooser.handleVersionHandshakeChunk(ProtocolChooser.java:95)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.transport.SocketTransportHandler.chooseProtocolVersion(SocketTransportHandler.java:109)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.transport.SocketTransportHandler.channelRead(SocketTransportHandler.java:58)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.handlerRemoved(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:219)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerRemoved0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:631)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:428)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.transport.TransportSelectionHandler.switchToSocket(TransportSelectionHandler.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.transport.TransportSelectionHandler.decode(TransportSelectionHandler.java:81)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:642)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:565)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:479)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am running these tests on a single mac laptop pro (not clustered or anything yet). An i7 16GB of ram.

I am running some spark scala code that uses the neo4j connector.  When I run it on small data sets it works fine, when I let it rip on processing all the data in a neo4j database, it times out after running for a good while (several hours).  Usually with me having to reset the community edition restarting the neo4j server.   Is there some setting somewhere where I can adjust this time out? Either in Spark/Scala or in neo4j configs?

```
org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Failed to establish connection with server. Make sure that you have a server with bolt enabled on localhost:7687
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient.negotiateProtocol(SocketClient.java:197)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient.start(SocketClient.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnection.<init>(SocketConnection.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:52)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool.acquire(InternalConnectionPool.java:113)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalDriver.session(InternalDriver.java:53)
    at org.neo4j.spark.Executor$.execute(Neo4j.scala:360)
    at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4jRDD.compute(Neo4j.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do you have any log entries from neo4j that might shed some light?

Comment: Good call updated my question.

Comment: I'm not really a neo4j expert, but from the neo4j logs, it looks likely that you're running into some limit on the number of threads.  Could be a limit on the number of threads a process on your Mac can spawn (though it looks like that defaults to over 10k, so it's unlikely), but it could also be a per-user thread limit.  Not a Mac user either, so I don't know how practical this is, but running neo4j as a different user.

Comment: Let me try this, it is only on this large data set.  I am not sure how greedy neo4j can be for threads and I am not really a mac user either (just what I have in the office) ....but gives me something to go on and look at

Comment: As far as I recall, every query you do on Neo4j consumes only one thread (even if the query planner has properly parallelised the data fetches). I would guess that your out of memory error is actually some JVM configuration on Neo4j. Did you try to access the same Neo4j instance, with the same data, outside spark?

Comment: I have java code that would do similar calculations from neo4j (just totally un parallelised)